# C++ getter method for private variable not working properly(Only have Java experience)

Tags: c++

My header file

```
class Roster {
    private:
        Degree degree = NETWORK;
        int addFlag = 0;
        Student* classRosterArray[5] = { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };
    public:
        void add(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, 
                 int age, int daysToComplete1, int daysToComplete2, int daysToComplete3, Degree degreeProgram);
        void remove(string studentId);
        void printAll();
        void printByDegreeProgram(int degreeProgram);
        void printDaysInCourse(string studentId);
        void printInvalidEmails();
        Student* getClassRosterArray();
        ~Roster();

 };
```

My getter method in CCP file

```
Student* Roster::getClassRosterArray() {
    return *classRosterArray;
}
```

My main() in CCP

```
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        cout << "Student ID :: " << roster.getClassRosterArray()[k].getStudentId() << endl;
}
```

And it only takes out the first Student object, for the second index in array is empty....

Pleaese help! it is my first trying C++.!!

Comment: "*it is my first trying C++*" - you shouldn't be using pointers then. For arrays, consider `std::array` (if the size is fixed and known at compile time) or `std::vector`, which is basically Java's `ArrayList`.

Comment: `Roster::getClassRosterArray()` should be `return classRosterArray;`

Comment: @josh7115 if I return classRosterArray; it gives me an error saying "return value type does not matched the function type".

Comment: The return type should be `Student **`  that said, I would recommend using `vector` instead of arrays like that.

Comment: Ok ..it should be `Student** Roster::getClassRosterArray() { return classRosterArray; }`

Comment: @josh7115, then it throws an error on 3rd code saying "expression must have class type" !! but it looks going correct way

Comment: @ChrisMM, yeah Student ** looks correct way but it throws another error saying "expression must have class type"...!!!

Comment: Thanks to josh7115,ChrisMM | I found it I changed Student* to Student**, also roster.getClassRosterArray()[k].getStudentId() to roster.getClassRosterArray()[k]->getStudentId() and works perfectly! Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I will propose this change :

```
Student* getClassRosterArray( int ) ;

...
Student* Roster::getClassRosterArray(int id) {
    return classRosterArray[id];
}
...
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        cout << "Student ID :: " << roster.getClassRosterArray(k)->getStudentId() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the member without losing its size information, you might do

```
class Roster {
private:
    Student* classRosterArray[5] = { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };
    // ...
public:
    auto getClassRosterArray() -> Student* (&)[5] { return classRosterArray;}
    // ...
};
```

Ugly syntax :/

`std::array<Student*, 5>` has more regular syntax:

```
class Roster {
private:
    std::array<Student*, 5> classRosterArray{{ nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr }};
    // ...
public:
    std::array<Student*, 5>& getClassRosterArray() { return classRosterArray;}
    // ...
};
```

As `Student` seems not polymorphic, not using pointer seems even simpler with `std::vector`:

```
class Roster {
private:
    std::vector<Student> classRosterArray;
    // ...
public:
    std::vector<Student>& getClassRosterArray() { return classRosterArray;}
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You declare an array of `Student*`, in other words you declare a `Student**`.

The get method return the a Student* and not a Student** or better a Student*[].

This cause you problem. In other words you return only the first element of the array.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are different, and it is not possible to return an array